# SQL Query Help to get Quiz statistics

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I'm coding a quiz web application and i need help.
I've got three tables

```
Nicknames : |USER_ID|NICKNAME|
```

that stores USER_ID(auto increment) and NICKNAME registered to my system.

```
Questions : |QUESTION_ID|QUESTION_TEXT|RIGHT_ANSWER|
```

that contains QUESTION_ID(auto increment value),QUESTION_TEXT that is the text of the question to show to the user and RIGHT_ANSWER which is a char that can be 'A','B','C' or 'D'.

```
Answers : |USER_ID|QUESTION_ID|ANSWER_GIVEN|
```

USER_ID references Nicknames.USER_ID
QUESTION_ID references Questions.QUESTION_ID
ANSWER_GIVEN is the answer that user gave(and so it should be A,B,C or D as in Questions)

I need to count with a query how many correct answers each user gave for all questions in database.

(example of result)

```
NICKNAME     |TOTAL_CORRECT_ANSWERS

Nick1        |       0

Nick2        |       5
```

and so on...

Notice that i would like to get 0 in the SQL result if the user did not answer correctly at all.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`select usr.nick_name, count(ans.ans_given) from user usr, question que, answer ans
where usr.user_id = ans.user_id and que.question_id = ans.question_id
and que.right_ans = ans.ans_given group by usr.user_id`

That was the solution, but how to show 0 if an user did not answer anything correctly?(thanks szakwani)

Answer (score 0):

I am learning SQL these days and I tried your case last night.

There are two issues I think you should take into consideration when coding: make sure those didn't get any right answer nicknames get a 0 value, and those didn't take the exam get a 0 value, too.

To make sure you can understand clearly, here is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t3.NICKNAME, case when count(GIVEN_ANSWER) >0 then count(GIVEN_ANSWER) else 0 end as TOTAL_RIGHT_ANSWER 
 --to make sure those nicknames that get no answer right, and those didn't take the exam get a 0.
FROM 
Nicknames T3  --make sure the full list of nicknames
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT nickname,GIVEN_ANSWER
    FROM
    Answers t1
    LEFT JOIN Nicknames ON t1.user_id = Nicknames.user_id
    INNER JOIN questions ON t1.question_id = questions.question_id
        AND GIVEN_ANSWER = RIGHT_ANSWER
    ) T2 ON T3.NICKNAME = T2.NICKNAME
GROUP BY t3.NICKNAME   --all the nicknames with their right answers
```

I think it would be not correct when there are cases that different users get the same nickname. You can try if want to take that into consideration.

Answer (score -1):

```
select usr.nick_name, count(ans.ans_given) from user usr, question que, answer ans
where usr.user_id = ans.user_id and que.question_id = ans.question_id
and que.right_ans = ans.ans_given;
```

it would help if you could create the DDL in sql fiddle and we could have a working environment.

If you chose to vote down, kindly leave a comment.

Comment: Same as i did but i would like to show also 0 if nickname did not answer anything well. I will provide a dump soon.

Comment: Now how would you expect us to know what you did if you do not share it? Share the DDL.

Comment: Here is the dump : http://pastebin.com/cMmT49Tp